# Visual Studio Code Coverage not highlight covered code

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage

Debugging the test would trigger this breakpoint as can be seen in the image:

[image]

But running the test to analyze code coverage, would not highlight the code (not green, not red). As can be seen in the image:

[image]

Any idea what can cause that?